# how to use FetchEntityCollection instead of FetchEntity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, llblgenpro

I am trying to populate a kendo grid with data through the LLBL adapter. I am able to see a single result using a break point when I pass in a PK but I need to return the entire collection of results. The fields that need to be returned are BundleId, CarrierId, Date, IsSent

thank you

Controller

```
  public ActionResult BundleStatus()
    {

        return View();

    }

    //[HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult BundleStatusRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    //{
    //    DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
    //    CarrierBundleEntity bundle = new CarrierBundleEntity(6);
    //    adapter.FetchEntity(bundle);
    //    var results = bundle;
    //    return View(results);
    //}

    public ActionResult BundleStatusRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
        CarrierBundleEntity bundle = new CarrierBundleEntity();
        var Results = adapter.FetchEntityCollection(bundle);
       return Json(Results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

}
```

Error Message

```
The best overloaded method match for 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.FetchEntityCollection(SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.QueryParameters)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to bring back all the data at once.

```
public ActionResult BundleStatusRead() 
{ 
DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
EntityCollection allBundles = new EntityCollection(new CarrierBundleEntityFactory());
adapter.FetchEntityCollection(allBundles, null);  
var results = allBundles;
return View(results); }
```